# Prove that they form an arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

If   $\frac{1}{c+b},\frac{1}{c+a},\frac{1}{a+b}$ this is an arithmetic progression, prove that $a^2,b^2,c^2 $  is an arithmetic progresson as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the fractions in pair and express an arithmetic progression:

$$\frac{a-b}{(b+c)(c+a)}=\frac{b-c}{(c+a)(a+b)}$$

or

$$\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{c+a}=\frac{(b-c)(b+c)}{c+a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $m \geq n \geq p $ are in an arithmetic progression iff $m+p=2n$

Your problem is symmetric with respect to $a,b,c$, hence you can assume that $a\geq b \geq c$

If you apply the hint, what do you get?

Comment: i get $a^2+c^2=2b^2$

Comment: What does this tell you about $a^2, b^2, c^2$?

Comment: I dont know, what? That they are in an arithmetic progression?

Comment: Look at the hint

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to tell :), but i applied that arithmetic progression property on the first progression and get $2(c+a)(a+b)=2(a+c)$, will that help solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that
$$\frac{\frac{1}{c+b}+\frac{1}{a+b}}{2}=\frac{1}{c+a}$$
this is equivalent to

$$\frac{a^2+c^2}{2}=b^2$$